# i want to traverse over all the pages using "NEXT" button link to get all the items

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm getting an error: "Unhasable type: list" in the rules which i have defined to extract next-button link.

```
from scrapy.http import Request

from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider,Rule

from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

from walmart_sample.items import WalmartSampleItem


class MySpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = "my_spider"
    domain = ['Apparel']
    keyword = 'Bags'
    departments = {"All Departments": "0", "Apparel": "5438", "Auto": "91083", "Baby": "5427", "Beauty": "1085666","Books": "3920", "Electronics": "3944", "Gifts": "1094765", "Grocery": "976759", "Health": "976760","Home": "4044", "Home Improvement": "1072864", "Jwelery": "3891", "Movies": "4096", "Music": "4104","Party": "2637", "Patio": "5428", "Pets": "5440", "Pharmacy": "5431", "Photo Center": "5426","Sports": "4125", "Toys": "4171", "Video Games": "2636"}
    allowed_domains = ['walmart.com']
    denied_domains = ['reviews.walmart.com','facebook.com','twitter.com']
    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("http://www.walmart.com/search/search-ng.do?tab_value=all&search_query=%s&search_constraint=%s&Find=Find&pref_store=1801&ss=false&ic=16_\d*2&_mm=" %(keyword,departments.get(domain))),),restrict_xpaths=('//li[@class="btn-nextResults"]'),callback='parse',follow=True),)


    def start_requests(self):
        for domains in self.domain:
            if domains in self.departments:
                url = 'http://www.walmart.com/search/search-ng.do?search_query=%s&ic=16_0&Find=Find&search_constraint=%s' % (self.keyword, self.departments.get(domains))
                yield Request(url)


    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        links = hxs.select('//a[@class="prodLink ListItemLink"]/@href')
        last = hxs.select('//a[@class="SPPagNoLink jump next"]').extract()
        if last is None:
            for link in links:
                href = link.extract()
                yield Request('http://www.walmart.com/' + href, self.parse_data) 
        else:
            print "<<<<<Last Page>>>>>>"


    def parse_data(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        items=[]
        walmart=WalmartSampleItem()
        walmart['Title']=hxs.select('//h1[@class="productTitle"]/text()').extract()
        walmart['Price']=hxs.select('//span[@class="bigPriceText1"]/text()').extract()+hxs.select('//span[@class="smallPriceText1"]/text()').extract()
        walmart['Availability']=hxs.select('//span[@id="STORE_AVAIL"]/text()').extract()
        walmart['Description']=hxs.select('//span[@class="ql-details-short-desc"]/p/text()').extract()
       #walmart['Avg_Rating']=
       #walmart['Detailed_Rating']=
        items.append(walmart)
        return items
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/usr/bin/scrapy", line 4, in <module>
    execute()

  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 143, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)

  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 89, in _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)

  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 150, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)

  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/commands/crawl.py", line 47, in run
    crawler = self.crawler_process.create_crawler()

  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/crawler.py", line 87, in create_crawler
    self.crawlers[name] = Crawler(self.settings)

  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/crawler.py", line 25, in __init__
    self.spiders = spman_cls.from_crawler(self)

  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/spidermanager.py", line 35, in from_crawler
    sm = cls.from_settings(crawler.settings)

  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/spidermanager.py", line 31, in from_settings
    return cls(settings.getlist('SPIDER_MODULES'))

  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/spidermanager.py", line 22, in __init__
    for module in walk_modules(name):

  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 68, in walk_modules
    submod = import_module(fullpath)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/vivek/mywork/walmart_sample/walmart_sample/spiders/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
  File "/home/vivek/mywork/walmart_sample/walmart_sample/spiders/test.py", line 15, in MySpider
    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("http://www.walmart.com/search/search-ng.do?tab_value=all&search_query=%s&search_constraint=%s&Find=Find&pref_store=1801&ss=false&ic=16_\d*2&_mm=" %(keyword,departments.get(domain))),),restrict_xpaths=('//li[@class="btn-nextResults"]'),callback='parse',follow=True),)   


TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Can you paste your stack trace so we know the source of the error?

Comment: i have added the error screenshots!!

Answer (score 0):

The problematic bit is this:

```
departments.get(domain)
```

`domain` is a list and thus you need to specify which individual item in the list you want to use. In this case using `domain[0]` fixes the problem, and your rule becomes:

```
rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("http://www.walmart.com/search/search-ng.do?tab_value=all&search_query=%s&search_constraint=%s&Find=Find&pref_store=1801&ss=false&ic=16_\d*2&_mm=" %(keyword,departments.get(domain[0]))),),restrict_xpaths=('//li[@class="btn-nextResults"]'),callback='parse',follow=True),)
```

Comment: my main problem is to iterate over the pages following the link of next button.thanks for your solution but it doesn't resolve my problem.

Comment: If my answer fixes the error, then please update the question with the code change and provide details of the problem that is now occurring. :)

Comment: sorry about that but still I have same problem as mentioned in above comment!!
even using your fix also doesn't help me out! :(

Comment: this unhashable thing i got rid of by just adding an if statement....but going through next pages is still there

Comment: I'm having a look now, but if this is a CrawlSpider, then you should avoid overriding the `parse` callback as this is something that CrawlSpider uses internally. Also, it would be an idea to start with something simple that uses "Apparel" as a hard-coded department to verify that your rule is correct before expanding the code.